# Why couldn't I find the review source code on the html source code?

Tags: html, google-chrome, scrapy, scrape

I'm using Google chrome and trying to scrape all the reviews on this webpage.
http://www.nytimes.com/roomfordebate/2014/09/24/protecting-student-privacy-in-online-learning/student-data-collection-is-out-of-control
I know source code is more reliable since it's the same across different browser while inspect element is result interpreted by the browser.
I could locate the html using inspect element in chrome browser, but I couldn't locate the same information by search source code, why?

Comment: Presumably because the DOM is modified by JS after the page has loaded.

Comment: Use the network section in the Chrome debugger. You'll likely find the content coming through an AJAX call. And lucky for you, it might be in JSON, making it much easier to parse. ;)

Comment: @Quentin That's true, but I want to know how could I scrape them via source code knowing the fact they are even not in the source code.

Comment: @os1 — Reverse engineer the JavaScript. Reimplement what it does in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

There are dynamic elements present in the website. i noticed some elements are dynamically generated on page loads by loops, ajax, etc... so you cannot view the source code of the article.
here you can read the basic about dynamic pages: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_web_page

in brief, ajax will load contents from the database without a form submission and dynamic objects generated in a for loop or while loop wont have an exact source code. You may also read about responsive 
web page design, in which the website changes according to the size of the screen.
you can read basics from:- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Comment: ok, so you are saying if the elements are dynamically generated, there's no way I could scrape them, right? And if a website don't like be scraped, it could hide all the source code?

Comment: @os1 — You've already established that you can scrape them by having a browser engine render the page, so obviously that isn't the case.

Comment: i didn't say that there is no way to scrap a dynamically generated page. a dynamically generated web page is simply like a lamp before a customized web browser. Even Google chrome console window provides you almost all the elements. If you want to secure your page you have to adopt many other methods like prevention against sql injections (prepared statements), quick expire page session, prevent Chinese web crawlers and bolts to spot your website (htacess) and scrap it and etc...

Comment: what's wrong with Chinese web crawlers and bolts? I'm chinese. I do this for research purpose. Do you think only chinese make web crawlers and bolts? Are you racist.

Comment: @os1 ,No am not.i don't think only Chinese make web crawlers or bolts. it is necessary for every search engine and websites like yellowpages. am sorry to say the fact that more than 50% of Chinese web crawlers and bolts are used the information collected from websites for intruding into the websites as well as injecting malwares to websites. Its just business, those guys who do that are getting payed for it and as its a hard job, Chinese are doing it more sincerely. I don't belongs to any group and i do believe even terrorism is nothing apart from a good business.

Answer (score 0):

I recently studied this method because this is what my problem before. I want to get the correct answers for my online lms, but the review source code doesn't appear in the view source for what it supposed to be, because it is dynamically generated. But while studying the functions, while answering my activities and finished it and I submit my answers I noticed that (when the web is loading) the review source code shortly appears (for just seconds) due to it's auto correcting my answers but suddenly disappear after the web loading. And I'm thinking if it's possible to auto save it's file "review" source code so even it disappear I can check it for later.

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't reallyunderstand your answer. Which method? What is with the disappearing code? Please elaborate.